# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am getting this error all the time. Any idea?
I have added all the necessary libraries required. Anything wrong with tensorflow? I am not able to understand it.Trying to create a chat bot. The json file is ok. I have checked some videos, I guess I have to change the train_x and train_y data.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas
import nltk
import pickle
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD

lm = WordNetLemmatizer()
intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore = ['?', '!', '.', ',']

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(word_list)
        documents.append((word_list, intent['tag']))
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])


words =[lm.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore]
words = sorted(set(words))

classes = sorted(set(classes))
pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl','wb'))
pickle.dump(words, open('classes.pkl','wb'))

training = []
output = [0] * len(classes)

for document in documents:
    area = []
    word_pattern = document[0]
    word_pattern = [lm.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_pattern]
    for word in words:
        if word in word_pattern:
            area.append(1) if word in word_pattern else area.append(0)

    output_rw = list(output)
    output_rw[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([area,output_rw])

random.shuffle(training)
training= np.array(training)
train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=0.000001, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save('chatbot model.model')
print("Done")
```

Comment: Usually this means you are trying to make a Tensor from an object dtype array.  That in turn is produced from a list with elements that vary in shape.  Check the shape and dtype of things like `np.array(train_x)`.  Pay attention to the error traceback, and use that to identify exactly where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Only 1's are appended to the area due to a faulty `if` condition in your code, resulting in a variable number of elements in each row of train_x. Since an array must have the same amount of elements in all of its rows, the list is not converted to `np.array`. Kindly change the code as follows.

```
for word in words:
        # Remove if word in word_pattern:
        area.append(1) if word in word_pattern else area.append(0)
```

Please find the working code [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/79224c27618e515ac03335c9e7984999/untitled196.ipynb). Thank you!